# внутренности встроенных функций

Tags: javascript, функции, alert

Хотел бы узнать где найти или искать информацию по поводу внутренностей (мяса) встроенных функций в JS.

Например:

```
function lol() {
    //some code;
}
alert(lol); // выдает информацию о функции, о её коде.
```

А когда пишешь `alert(alert)`; выдает `function alert() ( [native code] )`
Что за *native code*?
Пытался гуглить что то в роде: внутренности функции `alert`, как узнать код функции `alert` и т.д. Каждый раз выдает всякие примеры по её использованию и описание. Ну или я что-то не понимаю, и её код вообще другим образом сделан. Как она делает так, что при её вызове происходит именно это?

Comment: в репозитории хрома/файрфокса/другого бразуера. Это браузерные функции, не встроенные jsные

Comment: функция `alert` предоставляется браузером, и ее реализация зависит от конкретного браузера. Чтобы найти ее исходники, нужно смотреть исходники конкретного браузера. Предположительно для хромиума исходники вот: https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:third_party/blink/renderer/core/frame/local_dom_window.cc;l=1038;drc=c77ccde5b729af314595e528d89837d2c890f94f;bpv=0;bpt=1?originalUrl=https:%2F%2Fcs.chromium.org%2F

Comment: @ThisMan, _Это браузерные функции, не встроенные jsные_ - встроенные jsные, тоже выводят `[native code]`, например _function Array() { [native code] }_

Comment: Речь ведь про `alert` идет, при чем тут `Array`?

Comment: @ThisMan, при том, что возможно, имелись ввиду не только браузерные функции, а вообще функции выводящие _native code_, и алерт только в качестве примера был.

Comment: Да. alert в качестве примера. Мне интересно узнать в целом, где искать внутренности встроенных функци, не только браузерных, но и js'ных в целом.

Comment: @nx4n, нужно различать функции являющиеся частью js, и функции предоставляемые браузером либо другой средой, где работает движок js. Их реализация может быть в разных местах. Так функции предоставляемые браузером, очевидно, стоит искать в исходниках браузера, в то время как стандартные функции js, стоит искать в исходниках конкретного js движка

Comment: @Grundy, спасибо за информацию. Вопрос исчерпан. До движков я еще не дошел :)